# When does a module go out of scope in Fortran 90/95?

Tags: module, fortran, fortran90, fortran95

My intended use is

```
program main
  use mod

  external sub

  call sub
end program main

subroutine sub
  ! code here calls subroutines in mod
end subroutine sub
```

Specifically, will `module mod` be in scope in `subroutine sub`?  Also, I'd be interested to know more generally when a module is in/out of scope.  I'm using gfortran 4.6.1, if it matters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not in scope of subroutine sub, as sub cannot call routines or use variables from mod, because `sub` is not part of the program `main`. They have nothing in common, are separate compilation units and only may call each other (if they are callable).

Consider this:

```
program main

  external sub

  call sub
end program main

subroutine sub
  use mod
  ! code here calls subroutines in mod
end subroutine sub
```

Here, you can use variables and routines from `mod` in `sub`, because `sub` explicitly uses `mod`.

Another example, where `sub` is an internal procedure of `main`:

```
program main
  use mod

  call sub

  contains

    subroutine sub
      ! code here calls subroutines in mod
    end subroutine sub

end program main
```

Also in this case you can use things from `mod` in `sub` because everything from `main` is in scope in `sub`.

Finally, in this case `mod` is not in scope, it is similar to the original case.

```
program main
  use mod
  use mod2

  call sub
end program main

module mod2

  contains

    subroutine sub

      ! code here calls subroutines in mod
    end subroutine sub

end module mod2
```

Another issue is the undefining of module variables, when they go out of scope. Fortran 2008 solved this by making all module variables implicitly `save`.

Comment: That's helpful, thanks.  So in general, a module is in scope inside a program unit that "uses" it, but not in external units called by the main unit?

Comment: What about the case where you have `sub1` defined in `mod1` and you have a subroutine `sub2` which accepts an external routine as an argument.  Could you pass `sub1` to `sub2`?  `call sub1(sub2)` ?  *it works with `gfortran` ...

Comment: Your second example (with the internal procedure) fails to compile with gfortran (and it should fail with other compilers too I'd think).  You can't declare a procedure as external and then provide an internal procedure of the same name.

Comment: The extra external definition is just a copy-paste error of course, thanks for notice. It can be deleted everywhere btw., a subroutine does not have to be explicitly declared as external.

Comment: Fr the first comment: I think it should work. I don't see any reason why not, but I did not study the standard for that.